# how do I apply normalize function to pandas string series?

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

I would like to apply the following function to a dataframe series:

`unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', c.lower().decode('utf-8')).encode('ascii','ignore')`

I (sort of) understand how I can do stuff like `db.cname.str.lower()`, but I'm not able to generalize to any other function after the string accessor.

How do I apply the `normalize` function to all members of the series?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `c` is your string column.  `map` is used to apply a function elementwise (and of course you wouldn't have to chain it all together like this)

```
df[c] = (df[c].str.lower()
              .str.decode('utf-8')
              .map(lambda x: unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', x))
              .str.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe since Pandas version 1.0, one can use the [built-in method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.normalize.html) for the normalization, so this part can be carried out with:

```
df[a].str.normalize('NFKD')
```

If I understood correctly your function, the order of `lower()` and `decode()` are switched because you cannot put bytes to lower case, only characters, but bytes are the input of `decode()`. So assuming `c` are bytes and `d[a]` is a Series of bytes, it could be done with:

```
df[a].str.decode('utf-8').str.lower().str.normalize('NFKD').str.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```